# datepicker jquery ui with limits

Tags: jquery

I have 2 datepickers, in the first datepicker you can select a date from today ahead, in the second datepicker  the limits must be:
5 days after of the date from the first datepicker as mindate
90 days after of the date from the first datepicker as maxdate

I have this but it doesn´t work, somebody can help me?

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
});

function calc(){
var date_min = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate', '+5d');
var date_max = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate', '+90d'); 
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ minDate: date_min,maxDate: date_max });
}
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onChange="calc()"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simple script for your problem http://jsfiddle.net/KBq48/35/

```
$("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").datepicker({
minDate: "+0",
maxDate: "+2Y",
defaultDate: "+1w",
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',   

beforeShow: function() {        
    var thedate = new Date( $('#datepicker1').val() );
    var minDate = new Date(thedate.setDate(thedate.getDate() + 5));
    var maxDate = new Date(thedate.setDate(thedate.getDate() + 90));
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate);
 }   
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just grab the value, and set the min and max from there. Try this:

```
function calc(){
    var date_value = $('#datepicker').datepicker().val();
    var dateValue = new Date(date_value);    
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '+5d',
        maxDate: '+90d',
        defaultDate: dateValue,
    });
}
```